# Logical Error in Java Program

Tags: java

I have created two methods that take in a number and should count from that number to 0 and print it out. One method incorporates a while loop, which works fine. The other method uses a for loop. But for some reason, I'm not getting the expected output in the method that uses a for loop. How come?

```
 import java.util.*; 

 public class Methods 
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         int n = 10;   
         countdown(n); 
         countdown2(n); 
     }

     public static int countdown(int num)
     {
         while(num >= 0)
         {
             System.out.println(num); 
             num--;
         }
             return 0; 
     }

     public static int countdown2(int number)
     {
         for(int i = number; i <= number; i--)
         {
             System.out.println(number);
             number--;
         }
             return 0;        
     }
 }
```

Comment: you're both decreasing number and using it as an exit condition for the loop,so it'll only loop number/2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ever a program is behaving in a way which does make sense, the first thing you should try is use the debugger to debug your code.  This allows you to step through the program line by line and see what all the values are

---

If you have a while loop you can exchange it with a for loop like so (provide you don't have a continue statement)

```
for({initialise variable};{condition};{update expression}) {
    {do something}
}
```

with

```
{initialise variable}
while({condition}) {
    {do something}
    {update expression}
}
```

or

```
{initialise variable}
while(true) {
    if ({condition}) break;
    {do something}
    {update expression}
}
```

or

```
{initialise variable}
if({condition}) 
  do {
    {do something}
    {update expression}
  } while({condition});
```

Answer (score 4):

Because of the way you've structured the for loop conditions:

1. `i` is initially set to the same value as `number`.
2. The loop continues while `i` is less than or equal to `number`.
3. `i` gets *decremented* every time round the loop.

Since `i` starts out as less than or equal to `number`, and gets smaller, you're not going to exit the loop any time soon.  (This will only happen when `i` gets down to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and then underflows to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` on the next iteration).

Changing the condition to `i > 0` would be one way of resolving this; or you could initially set `i` to zero and increment it each time round the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
 for(int i = number; i <= number; i--)
```

check loop your count is starting from number to number only. 
you should count from number to 0.

```
  for(int i = number; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int countdown2(int number)
 {
     for(;number>=0;)
     {
         System.out.println(number);
         number--;
     }
         return 0;        
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
public static int countdown2(int number)
{
    for(int i = number; i >= 0; i--)
    {
       System.out.println(number);
       number--;
    }
    return 0;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the second loop should be

```
i >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int countdown2(int number)
 {
     for(int i = number; i >= 0; i--)
     {
         System.out.println(number);
         number--;
     }
     return 0;        
 }
```